# Is it possible to make a copy of variable and refactor only the name of new variable in Android Studio?

Tags: java, refactoring

Say I have

```
static final Map<..,..> MAP = new HashMap<>();
static 
{
MAP.put(..,..);
...
}
```

and I want to copy this and refactor the name of copy to MAP_2, so that I would have a map like this

```
static final Map<..,..> MAP_2 = new HashMap<>();
static 
{
MAP_2.put(..,..);
...
}
```

in the same project. Is this possible, without changing all the names one by one in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Create a new class
Copy paste the Map in the New Class
Refactor